# Array passing to function in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, function, basic

I have this code and the problem, that **PoleCisel2** used in function **nulovac** does not work with **PoleCisel**, so in **PoleCisel** aren't any items in the function.

Option Explicit On

```
Module Module1

    Function nulovac(PoleCisel() As Integer) As Integer()
        Dim i As Integer, UpravenePole() As Integer
        ReDim PoleCisel(0 To 9), UpravenePole(0 To 9)
        Dim vypis As String

        For i = 0 To 9
            If PoleCisel(i) < 0 Then
                UpravenePole(i) = 0
            Else
                UpravenePole(i) = PoleCisel(i)
            End If
        Next i
        nulovac = UpravenePole
    End Function
    Sub Main()
        Dim UpravenePole2(9) As Integer, PoleCisel2() As Integer, vypis As String, vypis2 As String, i As Integer
        ReDim PoleCisel2(9)
        vypis = ""
        vypis2 = ""
        For i = 0 To 9
            PoleCisel2(i) = Int((Rnd() - 0.5) * 200)
        Next i
        UpravenePole2 = nulovac(PoleCisel2)
        For i = 0 To 9
            vypis = vypis + Str(PoleCisel2(i)) + ", "
            vypis2 = vypis2 + Str(UpravenePole2(i)) + ", "

        Next i
        MsgBox(vypis + Chr(10) + Chr(10) + vypis2)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, in the function must not be ReDim.